How to add JDBC driver for database on the spark classpath in EMR Serverless using AWS Console?
I am submitting job (which needs to pull data from MySQL) to EMR serverless from AWS Console.
Here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html I read that I need to do below but not certain how/where in AWS Console I should key this in?
./bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path mysql-connector-XXX.jar --jars mysql-connector-XXX.jar

If I ignore this step and submit the job then I get below error in stdOut
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o98.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

